# How can I sort xml using xsl updating nodes to it's position number relative to it's parent?

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have xml with Nodes elements unsorted with RowNumber sequence. I want to sort my xml but update the RowNumber element with the new sequence number

**Input** (RowNumber is sequencial) and can have more fields as Row elements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Row>
      <field_01>G</field_01>
      <field_02>foo</field_02>
      <RowNumber>1</RowNumber>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <field_01>A</field_01>
      <field_02>foo</field_02>
      <RowNumber>2</RowNumber>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <field_01>B</field_01>
      <field_02>foo</field_02>
      <RowNumber>3</RowNumber>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <field_01>H</field_01>
      <field_02>foo</field_02>
      <RowNumber>4</RowNumber>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <field_01>D</field_01>
      <field_02>foo</field_02>
      <RowNumber>5</RowNumber>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <field_01>M</field_01>
      <field_02>foo</field_02>
      <RowNumber>6</RowNumber>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <field_01>U</field_01>
      <field_02>foo</field_02>
      <RowNumber>7</RowNumber>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <field_01>W</field_01>
      <field_02>foo</field_02>
      <RowNumber>8</RowNumber>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <field_01>Z</field_01>
      <field_02>foo</field_02>
      <RowNumber>9</RowNumber>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <field_01>L</field_01>
      <field_02>foo</field_02>
      <RowNumber>10</RowNumber>
   </Row>
</root>
```

**Current XSLT** ... from reading i probably have to use xlt:number or position() but I couldn't understand how to apply it here
so, my current XSL sorts it but i could not update RowNumber with the new sequence

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Row">
            <xsl:sort select="field_01" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Desired Output**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Row>
      <field_01>A</field_01>
      <field_02>foo</field_02>
      <RowNumber>1</RowNumber>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <field_01>B</field_01>
      <field_02>foo</field_02>
      <RowNumber>2</RowNumber>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <field_01>D</field_01>
      <field_02>foo</field_02>
      <RowNumber>3</RowNumber>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <field_01>G</field_01>
      <field_02>foo</field_02>
      <RowNumber>4</RowNumber>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <field_01>H</field_01>
      <field_02>foo</field_02>
      <RowNumber>5</RowNumber>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <field_01>L</field_01>
      <field_02>foo</field_02>
      <RowNumber>6</RowNumber>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <field_01>M</field_01>
      <field_02>foo</field_02>
      <RowNumber>7</RowNumber>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <field_01>U</field_01>
      <field_02>foo</field_02>
      <RowNumber>8</RowNumber>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <field_01>W</field_01>
      <field_02>foo</field_02>
      <RowNumber>9</RowNumber>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <field_01>Z</field_01>
      <field_02>foo</field_02>
      <RowNumber>10</RowNumber>
   </Row>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ty it this way?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Row">
            <xsl:sort select="field" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="field"/>
                <RowNumber><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></RowNumber>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> my current XSL sorts it

I don't think so. It *tries* to sort by a `@field` **attribute** - but your XML does not have such attribute.

---

### Edit:

In view of your modified input,I suggest you try a somewhat different approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- sort Rows -->
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Row">
            <xsl:sort select="field_01" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- renumber -->
<xsl:template match="Row">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <RowNumber><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></RowNumber>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- suppress old numbering -->
<xsl:template match="RowNumber"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: you are right, @field is mistake ... I will update the question ... and thanks for the response ...

Comment: Michael.hor... question? ... So, if i have more fields , i have to specify in my copy ... ?? for example,
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:copy-of select="field"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="field_1"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="field_2"/>
<RowNumber><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></RowNumber>
</xsl:copy>

Is there is easy way?

Comment: @addisu You could do `<xsl:apply-templates>` instead. If you need more details, please edit your question (or post a new one).

Comment: michael.hor257k ... I updated my question with <xsl:apply-templates>